# Is it possible to run Overwatch with an unsupported graphics card on Linux?

Tags: linux, gaming, directx

Is it possible to run Overwatch with an unsupported graphics card on a Linux distro?
The question here is not if I can run the game on Linux, I'm simply wondering that if I ran the game on Linux will I be able to bypass the restriction of the fact that it's an unsupported graphics card?

My graphics card is: Nvidia GeForce 9600M GT (it supports up to DirectX 10 i believe) and I think it should be able to run the game at 30 fps at least. (https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-9600m-gt.c1518)

here's the list of GPU that are supported: https://battle.net/support/article/35895

I might be misinformed but I think Overwatch is able to run on directx 10. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it hurt to try?

Comment: I could try it but I prefer asking because maybe there's some sort of driver I gotta install?

Comment: It is possible, sure it's possible, provided the software does not do a requirement check.  If the hardware is old enough it might not support the proper revisions of DirectX or Vulcan in order for the software to run.  **If Overwatch requires DX11 and you only have a card that supports DX10 then the software cannot run.**

Comment: Alright I'll try it when I have time and I'll answer to this post reporting if it worked or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I did more research and Overwatch needs DirectX 10.1 to run, I'm not sure 100% about this but I researched how to install the game on Ubuntu and it requires Vulkan to install Litrus and since my graphics card doesn't support Vulkan, this means that no, it won't work.

edit: i tried with wine and still didn't work